# SharePoint 2013 and InfoPath forms incompatible

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, forms-services

When using my published InfoPath form in SP2013 I find the users that have MSO 2013 are able to use the form as for those who are on MSO 2010 this is the error.
[image: InfoPath error]

This article I found while scouring the web
'edit the InfoPath template within the document library in SharePoint > Form Options > Compatibility, change it to InfoPath filler form 2010. It still works for me and I have version 2013, so now it allows users with older versions to use it as well. I confirmed with the affected users that they can now access the form'
I am not sure if this will work as I do not have the options when I get into the properties. 
I need a solution where the form will work in both users of MSO 2010 and users of MSO 2013.
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Does anyone have any idea??

Comment: Is there a way to make MSO InfoPath 2010 work with MSO InfoPath 2013??